# add plus or minus in awk if no match

Tags: regex, awk

I am trying to match all the lines in the below file to match.  The `awk` will do that the problem is that the lines that do not match should be within plus or minus 10.  I am not sure how to tell `awk` that the if a match is not found then use either `plus` or `minus` the coordinates in `file`.  If no match is found after that then no match is in the file. Thank you :).

**file**

```
955763
957852
976270
```

**bigfile**

```
chr1    955543  955763  chr1:955543-955763  AGRN-6|gc=75
chr1    957571  957852  chr1:957571-957852  AGRN-7|gc=61.2
chr1    970621  970740  chr1:970621-970740  AGRN-8|gc=57.1
```

**awk**

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1];next}$3 in A' file bigfile > output
```

**desired output** (same as bigfile)

```
chr1    955543  955763  chr1:955543-955763  AGRN-6|gc=75
chr1    957571  957852  chr1:957571-957852  AGRN-7|gc=61.2
```

Comment: What do you want the output to look like? Is there any difference between a line that matched exactly and one that is in the +-10 range?

Comment: I added the output to the edit and there is no difference.  Thank you :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no difference between a row that matches and one that's close, you could just set all of the keys in the range in the array:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { for (i = -10; i <= 10; ++i) A[$1+i]; next } 
$3 in A' file bigfile > output
```

The advantage of this approach is that only one lookup is performed per line of the big file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run a loop on array `a`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {
   a[$1]
   next
}
{
  for (i in a)
     if (i <= $3+10 && i >= $3-10)
        print
}' file bigfile > output
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data already produces the desired output (all exact match).

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} $3 in a{print; next} 
              {for(k in a) 
                 if((k-$3)^2<=10^2) {print $0, " --> within 10 margin"; next}}' file bigfile

chr1    955543  955763  chr1:955543-955763  AGRN-6|gc=75
chr1    957571  957852  chr1:957571-957852  AGRN-7|gc=61.2
chr1    976251  976261  chr1:976251-976261  AGRN-8|gc=57.1  --> within 10 margin
```

I added a fake 4th row to get the margin match